# 質問が質問者の以前質問した内容が原因と思われる場合の対処

Tags: 討議

質問者が1つ目の質問として「[配列から重複取り出しを防ぐ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27841/)」についての質問をされました。
内容は「PHPでDOMの出力を行う」ものでしたが
上記の質問が未解決のまま、2つめの質問「[phpの値にcssを反映したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27896/)」が投稿されました。
質問の内容から1つ目の質問の延長線上の質問であることは想定がつきましたが、
1つ目の質問の不具合が原因である可能性が高いです。

この場合、質問の重複とは少し違うのですが、
どう言った対処をするのが正解なのでしょうか？
クローズにしても理由が分からず、とりあえず回答しました。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

色々考えましたが **コメントで注意**をしたり、そのコードは問題ないから、前の質問の不具合が原因ということを**回答として投稿**したりすればいいと思います。

### 理由

回答の場合

- それが原因 という回答になる

コメントの場合

- コメントで前の質問が解決しているか？という情報の追加
- 作成者が投稿を改善するのに役立つ建設的な指摘を残すことができる

順番としては、解決しているのに承認、回答していないという可能性があるためコメントし、まだ解決していないということが分かったら回答という感じですね。解決していたら自己回答を促したり承認をしてもらったりすればいいと思います。

Comment: そうですね、概ね同意します。気になるのは、結果としてその質問が前質問に起因する場合、該当の質問がゴミとして残り続けることですね。、なので疑わしい場合は回答の通りで、前質問に起因すると分かったらクローズか削除を促す……で、どうでしょうか？

Comment: @Myaku それでいいと思います